# CEGUI doesn't work

Tags: c++, ogre, cegui

I've Ogre3D SDK v1.9 and CEGUI 0.8 and here's my problem .
I followed the tutorial in the wiki of cegui and it says me that I have to use cmake. That's what I did but when I click on the button 'Configure' there is an error :

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory C:/CEGUI/cegui/src/RendererModules/Ogre
```

BUT even i get this error I can continue and click on the button 'generate' anyway.

However when the build is done, i try to build cegui.svn and i get just one error :

```
Creating library C:/CEGUI/build/lib/CEGUIOgreRenderer-0_d.lib and object 
23>C:\CEGUI\build\bin\CEGUIOgreRenderer-0_d.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 106 unresolved externals
```

and a lot of `external symbol unresolved` before this error.

Actually, I noticed that `CEGUIOgreRenderer-0_d.dll` wasn't in my folder , I suppose visual studio failed to make the dll file.

Can you help me please? :)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need the get the Boost library for it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? :(

Comment: The tutorial has been updated with information about boost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to config the boost library dir into `system environment path` before you build `CEGUI`.

Following are the variable and its sample value:

```
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR      G:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0\boost
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR      G:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0\boost\lib
BOOST_ROOT            G:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0\boost
```

Check them after you click cmake-gui `configure`.

Besides, the link error may also caused by wrong link configure, for visual studio, check the `Project -- Property -- Linker -- Additional ...`, and add the specific `xxx.lib` at that box.